# Illegal characters in XML - java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm creating a program which checks the legitimacy of a given URL. I've already created my own algorithm for this, but now I want to add PhishTank's services into my program.

They provide services where you can directly query a URL from their website, but they have set a certain quota on the number of queries you can make per day. The other option, which I'm going with, is to simply download their database and work with it locally, without restrictions.

The file you get is in XML, and found some code to test with, but it seems like their XML contains illegal characters (such as unicode 0x07 -- the [BEL] character) inside CDATA, and so the parsing throws me an exception.

```
<url><![CDATA[http://shaghaf-edu.com/sign-in/??msg=InvalidOnlineIdException&amp;id[BEL]da9ca9b23227a572d1fb5ff4ff91e3&amp;lpOlbResetErrorCounter=0l=&amp;request_locale=en-us]]></url>
```

I've done a bit of searching and all I've found is solutions that seem fine to rather small XML-files. The one I'm working with is close to 2.7 million lines -- I'm not sure how efficiently a regex would work in this case or a char-to-char comparison.

I should note that their database is updated hourly, and has to be redownloaded. So cleaning the file once manually isn't an option.

So I'm wondering if there is any fast and efficient way of solving this problem?

I don't have the exact code with me, but I use is a very slight variation of this which I found here on StackOverflow:

```
private void start() throws Exception
{
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/AutoLogin/resource/web.xml");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    Document doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());
    NodeList descNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("description");

    for(int i=0; i<descNodes.getLength();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(descNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
    }
}

private Document parseXML(InputStream stream)
throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory objDocumentBuilderFactory = null;
    DocumentBuilder objDocumentBuilder = null;
    Document doc = null;
    try
    {
        objDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        objDocumentBuilder = objDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        doc = objDocumentBuilder.parse(stream);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }       

    return doc;
}
```

Comment: It seems a bit strange that they would have such characters in their XML - are you sure you're reading with the correct charset?

Comment: @EvanKnowles, I haven't really thought about this to be honest. The charset (as defined in the xml-file itself) is utf-8. Any browser or text-editor I open the file with compain that there is an error. Also some googling about it showed a couple of results where people say it's broken. I'll look into this though, thanks.

Comment: @GhostCat, I saw your last comment buddy. I have not tried what you suggested and so I cannot accept something I have not tried.

Comment: Fine with me. I am merely trying to get as much order into old and new stuff as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Answering by asking a question ...

Why not write a simple pre-processing utility?

It could read the XML file as is (line by line); and do whatever is required to turn that content into "correct" XML.

In other words: you should explicitly distinguish between the task of "preparing your input", and "actually working that xml input". This will also make it **much** easier to do fine tuning. If you find that regular expressions are too expensive; then just change the the "pre-processor" to not use them. And afterwards, easily measure the effects on runtime ...

Comment: Yeah, but I wouldn't think that would really differ from any of the other solutions I've found. I mean how would you do that in an efficient matter? Do a regex-check on 2.7 million lines of markup?

Comment: @Chris this is an infrequent action so efficiency really isn't that important. And I don't see how regular expressions have a use case here, this to me looks like basic token replacement. You grind through the 2.7 million lines and you cleanup what you don't want. But before that I'd check with the supplier to ask what the deal is, more likely if the data is actually bad they have a problem that needs solving.

Comment: @Gimby, good Point. Yeah, I sent them an email so let's see if they'll repond. I tried the JSON alternative from their website, but I'm getting errors on that one too.... shoot me.